# How do I post a photo to a Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I need to post an image to a group and I want the image to only be visible to the people on the group?

It looks like there's a bug or something and it's impossible to just post to the groups photos:
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19157

Is there a workaround? If I can't upload "to the group", how can I simulate it so that only people on the group can see the image I am posting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gah. Figured it out.

The no_story flag that works when uploading photos to an album or user photos causes the call to fail when posting to groups. God. I hate FB docs...

Solution: Post to /group_id/photos (which is undocumented.. yey) and W/Othe no_story flag.